# PHP loop by # to100, then by another #

Tags: php

I am working on a quick function that will take a number `$max` and if its below `100`, count by `5's` up to `$max`.

If `$max` is greater than `100`, it counts by 5's until it gets to `100`, then counts by 25's until it hits `$max`.

Example:

```
public function getDenominations($max)
{
    $start = 20;
    $output = [];

    // If max is less than 100, count by 5's
    if($max <= 100 ){
        for($i = $start; $i <= $max; $i += 5) {
            array_push($output, $i);
        }
        return $output;
    // Max is greater than 100, count by 5's up to 100, then by 25's
    }else{
        for($i = $start; $i <= $max; $i += 25) {
            array_push($output, $i);
        }
        return $output;
    }

}
```

**Expected Output w/ $max < 100:**

`5,10,15,20,25,....100`

**Expected Output w/ $max > 100:**

`5,10,15,20,25,....100,125,150,175,200`

My issue is that in the `$max > 100`, I am stuck first getting it to do the normal +5 count and then the +25. Currently, it just starts by 25's.

Current output when `$max = 500`:

`Array ( [0] => 20 [1] => 45 [2] => 70 [3] => 95 [4] => 120 [5] => 145 [6] => 170 [7] => 195 [8] => 220 [9] => 245 [10] => 270 [11] => 295 [12] => 320 [13] => 345 [14] => 370 [15] => 395 [16] => 420 [17] => 445 [18] => 470 [19] => 495 )`

Expecting 20-100 (by 5's) and then 100-500 (by 25's).

Comment: What is the current output? Or, on other words, what is the problem? I see no question here. Edit: please add current output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've simplified your code. You do not need two loops for this, you can just keep looping, and change how much you increase the current value with (5 or 25) until you hit the max number.

For example something like this:

```
$max = 130;
$output = [];
$current = 0;

// Keep looping until we hit max, or break out of the loop
while ($current <= $max) {
    // Find out if we should increase the current value with 5 or 25
    if ($current < 100) {
        $current += 5;
    }
    else {
        $current += 25;
    }

    // Make sure we do not add anything above the current max (e.g. max = 120, current = 110 + 25 = 135)
    if ($current > $max) {
        break;
    }

    // Add the current value to the output array
    $output[] = $current;
}

print_r($output);
```

Output

```
Array 
( 
    [0] => 5 
    [1] => 10 
    [2] => 15 
    [3] => 20 
    [4] => 25 
    [5] => 30 
    [6] => 35 
    [7] => 40 
    [8] => 45 
    [9] => 50 
    [10] => 55 
    [11] => 60 
    [12] => 65 
    [13] => 70 
    [14] => 75 
    [15] => 80 
    [16] => 85 
    [17] => 90 
    [18] => 95 
    [19] => 100 
    [20] => 125 
)
```

[Try it online here](https://3v4l.org/EXjIV)

Answer (score 0):

like this - in javascript?

```
max = 200
for (i = 1; i < max; i++) {
    out = i * 5;
    console.log(out <= 100 ? out : (i * 5 * 5) - 400);
}

5
10
15
20
25
30
35
40
45
50
55
60
65
70
75
80
85
90
95
100
125
150
175
200
225
250
275
300
325
350
375
400
425
450
475
500
525
550
575
600
625
650
675
700
```

Comment: This question is tagged with php?

Answer (score 0):

```
function getDenominations($max)
{
    $start = 20;
    $output = [];
    $incr = 5;
    $flag = false;

    for ($i = $start; $i <= $max; $i += $incr) {
        array_push($output, $i);

        if( $i >= 100 && $flag === false) {
            $incr = 25;
            $flag = true;
        }

    }
    return $output;
}

print_r(getDenominations(200));
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
[0] => 20
[1] => 25
[2] => 30
[3] => 35
[4] => 40
[5] => 45
[6] => 50
[7] => 55
[8] => 60
[9] => 65
[10] => 70
[11] => 75
[12] => 80
[13] => 85
[14] => 90
[15] => 95
[16] => 100
[17] => 125
[18] => 150
[19] => 175
[20] => 200
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you need can be written as simple as:

```
function getDenominations($max)
{
    $start = 20;
    $output = [];

    // Count by 5 from $start to 100 or $max, whichever is smaller
    for ($i = $start; $i <= min($max, 100); $i += 5) {
        $output[] = $i;
    }

    // Continue counting by 25 from 125 to $max, if $max is large enough
    for ($i = 125; $i <= $max; $i += 25) {
        $output[] = $i;
    }

    return $output;
}
```